# Why does getHeight() and getWidth() return 0 in the constructor? and how do I avoid that?

Tags: java, graphics2d, jcomponent

The following is my code, I'm trying to draw a line that extends from one end of the screen to another, but when I call getWidth() and getHeight() to create a line object the methods return 0. Why is this happening and how do I avoid this.

```
public class LineComponent extends JComponent {

private Shapes shape;

public LineComponent() {
    shape = new Line((int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(getHeight() * getHeight() + getWidth() * getWidth()))
,new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the component has not be laid out yet (it has no definable size).  Until the component is added to another container and that container is validated, the component won't be assigned a size.

How to fix depends on a number of factors, for example, you could use a [`ComponentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and listen for `componentResized` events, but do you want to know about all the size events?  When a component is first laid out, it might resized several times (to different sizes), which one do you care about?

Comment: I would need to resize my component, and I would need to know the original size when it's first laid out. Is there a way to avoid using ComponentListener

Comment: The "best" solution you have is to define the `preferredSize` of the component by overriding it's `getPreferredSize` method. There's no guarantee that the component will be laid out using this size though, but it would give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your main class then you first have to set the size and make it visible; otherwise there is no meaning to what width/height is:

```
setSize(100, 100);
setVisible(true);
```

in the constructor.

If this is not your main class and it is added to some other component then you have to move the line drawing to that class.